# "The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found" when create docker image for c# project

Tags: .net, image, docker

I have a c# solution with name Model.sln. It includes around 200 c# projects. I wanna create a docker image and run "dotnet build/public" commands in the image.

step 1: create Dockerfile for this solution.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:3.1.101-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /Users/Model/bin/Debug/Cli/netcoreapp3.1
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Model.dll"]
```

step 2:
run $ docker build .

step 3:
$docker run -d -t -v /Users/model:/source model

step 4:
$ docker exec -it magical_agnesi bash

step 5:
#dotnet publish
then I got the following message:
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

Don't know why I cannot run dotnet sdk commands in this image. It works in my mac system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have to have sdk image as runtime image does not have sdk.
Please add this image to your docker file.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as build
```

and Please check this one to get full dockerfile [example](https://medium.com/@zarkopafilis/asp-net-core-2-2-rest-api-14-running-in-docker-d2d097747831).